# Select rows which do not meets criteria

Tags: sql, oracle

I have FEATURE and FEATURE_DETAILS tables. FEATURE_DETAILS can have a lot of FEATUREs.

```
FEATURE_DETAILS
feature_deatails_id | feature_id
1                        1
1                        2
1                        4 
2                        1
2                        2
2                        4
2                        5
```

I have a problem in selecting feature_deatails_id's which do not have e.g. 5 feature_id. So the result should be:

```
feature_deatails_id | feature_id
1                     null
```

Comment: What's the problem? Can you show us your current statement?

Comment: Where is relation between tables? your example looks like  that there is just  one table

Comment: @OtoShavadze
Relation between tables is one(FEATURE ) to many (FEATURE_DETAILS).
Tabel with feature contains feature_id as PK and details.

Comment: @UlisesAndréFierro
I dont know how in the best way get output as I described in question. Tried joins but it didnt work. Another case that this table i returnd by select.

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your purpose

```
with data as (
          select 1 as feature_details_id, 1 feature_id from dual
    union select 1,2 from dual
    union select 1,4 from dual
    union select 2,1 from dual
    union select 2,2 from dual
    union select 2,4 from dual
    union select 2,5 from dual
)
select distinct feature_details_id, NULL feature_id from data
where feature_details_id not in (
      select feature_details_id from data
      where  feature_id = 5)
;
```

What the above query will do is -

1. Select the feature_details_id where feature = 5
2. Remove all those feature_details_id and select whatever is remaining

Comment: Please have in mind that `NOT IN` "sort of" misbehaves in the presence of `NULL` so, as a general advice either: a) prefer its `NOT EXISTS` "equivalent" (my personal preference because "it just works") or b) add appropiate `AND FOO IS NOT NULL` filters for each column involved in the `NOT IN` expression, unless the column already has a `NOT NULL` constraint

Answer (score 0):

With a NOT IN should be ok

```
SELECT DISTINCT FEATURE_DETAILS_ID, NULL AS FEATURE_ID 
    FROM FEATURE_DETAILS 
    WHERE FEATURE_DETAILS_ID NOT IN (
        SELECT FEATURE_DETAILS_ID FROM FEATURE_DETAILS WHERE FEATURE_ID = 5
    );
```

Answer (score -2):

select feature_deatails_id, null as feature_id
from feature_details
where feature_id != 5

This should solve your purpose.